# onTouchEvent for children of zoomed ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, zooming

For my [game Hashi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.aorlinn.bridges) I want to build a custom ViewGroup that allows zooming and scrolling (both axes), containing children that are affected on touches as well.

[image: This is how the ViewGroups looks]

I have set `setWillNotDraw(false)` and overwritten `draw(Canvas)` to use `canvas.scale(..)` and `canvas.translate(..)`:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleCenter.x, mScaleCenter.y);
    canvas.translate(mTranslation.x * mScaleFactor, mTranslation.y * mScaleFactor);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

But then I realized, that the `MotionEvent` parameter of the `onTouchEvent` for children is offset by the value I set with the translation (so they are detected, as if the container did not have any zoom or offset).

I tried to overwrite `dispatchTouchEvent` in the parent `ViewGroup` and adjust the coordinates of the event. But `MotionEvent` is final and can only be instantiated via `MotionEvent.obtain(..)`. And there is no version of `obtain` to accept multiple coordinates, when there is more than one finger down.
Is there any way to modify the MotionEvent parameters, so I don't need to do it in the `onTouchEvent` methods of the child views (that would be much more complex), or even a better approach to implement zoom and scroll?

I implemented my own zoom container because I need to control the touches strictly (children also listen to swipe gestures, but need to be intercepted, when a second finger is down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those having the same problem I post my solution (thanks again Andrew for [your help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74696078/5369727)).

**Update**

Because I experienced input issues while testing, I decided to use `onLayout` instead of `dispatchTouchEvent` and `draw` methods to apply scale factor and translation, as the old solution did only apply it to the drawing and the input detection, but the container still declared the position of the children in the original place. This was causing espresso to execute the touches in the wrong place. With this solution the children are completely offset, so it also works with testing (and probably other things I did not consider).

**Note** that both solutions only work, when you embed (an) other layout container(s) that match the parents size.
If you want to change that, you need to change the implementation of `onLayout`.

```
public class ZoomContainer extends ViewGroup
{
    /**
     * Limit the maximum/minimum scrolling to prevent scrolling the container,
     * so that no more children are visible.
     * The value is relative to the size of the container (so 0.1 means 10% of the size of this container)
     */
    protected float mTranslationBounds = 0.1f;
    /**
     * The translation to be applied to the container
     */
    protected PointF mTranslation;
    /**
     * The the current zoom factor.
     * It is initialized with a value smaller than 1, to append some empty space around the view.
     */
    protected float mScaleFactor = 0.95f;
    /**
     * The minimum scale factor to prevent endless zooming
     */
    protected float mScaleFactorMin = 0.8f;
    /**
     * The maximum scale factor to prevent endless zooming.
     */
    protected float mScaleFactorMax = 5.0f;
    /**
     * Used to indicate, whether or not this is the first touch event, which has no differences yet.
     */
    protected boolean mIsTouchStarted = false;
    /**
     * Distance of the fingers from the last touch event
     */
    protected float mStartDistance = 0;
    /**
     * Center of the two fingers from the last touch event.
     */
    protected PointF mStartTouchPoint = new PointF(0, 0);

    public ZoomContainer(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ZoomContainer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZoomContainer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel all child touch events, if there is more than one finger down.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        boolean intercept = ev.getPointerCount() > 1;
        if (intercept)
        {
            Log.d("TableView", "Intercepted");
            mIsTouchStarted = false;
        }
        return intercept;
    }

    protected void initializeTranslation()
    {
        if (mTranslation == null)
        {
            mTranslation = new PointF(getWidth() * (1 - mScaleFactor) / 2f,
                    getHeight() * (1 - mScaleFactor) / 2f);
            Log.d("TableView", "Translation: " + mTranslation);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the new zoom and scroll respecting the difference to the last touch event.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mIsTouchStarted = false;
                return true;
        }
        if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1)
        {
            mIsTouchStarted = false;
            return true;
        }
        float[] currentPointArray = new float[]{event.getX(0),
                event.getY(0),
                event.getX(1),
                event.getY(1)};
        float currentFingerDistance = getDistance(currentPointArray[0],
                currentPointArray[1],
                currentPointArray[2],
                currentPointArray[3]);
        // Read the current center of the fingers to determine the the new translation
        PointF currentPoint = getPoint(currentPointArray[0],
                currentPointArray[1],
                currentPointArray[2],
                currentPointArray[3]);
        if (mIsTouchStarted)
        {
            // 1 / oldScaleFactor - 1 / newScaleFactor is required to respect the relative translation,
            // when zooming (translation is always from the upper left corner,
            // but zooming should be performed centered to the fingers)
            float scaleFactorDifference = 1f / mScaleFactor;
            mScaleFactor = getBoundScaleFactor(mScaleFactor + (currentFingerDistance / mStartDistance - 1));
            scaleFactorDifference -= 1f / mScaleFactor;
            // Add the finger scroll since the last event to the current translation.
            PointF newTranslation = new PointF(mTranslation.x + (currentPoint.x - mStartTouchPoint.x) / mScaleFactor,
                    mTranslation.y + (currentPoint.y - mStartTouchPoint.y) / mScaleFactor);
            // Add the current point multiplied with the scale difference to make sure,
            // zooming is always done from the center of the fingers. Otherwise zooming would always be
            // applied from the upper left edge of the screen.
            newTranslation.x -= currentPoint.x * scaleFactorDifference;
            newTranslation.y -= currentPoint.y * scaleFactorDifference;
            mTranslation = getBoundTranslation(newTranslation);
        }
        mStartTouchPoint = currentPoint;
        mStartDistance = currentFingerDistance;
        mIsTouchStarted = true;
        requestLayout();
        return true;
    }

    protected float getBoundValue(float value, float min, float max)
    {
        return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
    }

    protected PointF getBoundTranslation(PointF translation)
    {
        translation.x = getBoundValue(translation.x,
                -(getWidth() * (mScaleFactor - 1) + getWidth() * mTranslationBounds),
                getWidth() * mTranslationBounds);
        translation.y = getBoundValue(translation.y,
                -(getHeight() * (mScaleFactor - 1) + getHeight() * mTranslationBounds),
                getHeight() * mTranslationBounds);
        return translation;
    }

    protected float getBoundScaleFactor(float scaleFactor)
    {
        return getBoundValue(scaleFactor, mScaleFactorMin, mScaleFactorMax);
    }

    protected PointF getPoint(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        return new PointF(getCenter(x1, x2), getCenter(y1, y2));
    }

    protected float getCenter(float position1, float position2)
    {
        return (position1 + position2) / 2f;
    }

    protected float getDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        float distanceX = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
        float distanceY = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        float width = (r - l);
        float height = (b - t);
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        initializeTranslation();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        l = (int) (mTranslation.x * mScaleFactor);
        r = (int) ((width + mTranslation.x) * mScaleFactor);
        t = (int) (mTranslation.y * mScaleFactor);
        b = (int) ((height + mTranslation.y) * mScaleFactor);

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }
}
```

**Old solution**

Using `dispatchTouchEvent` and `draw` methods to apply scale factor and tranlation:

```
public class ZoomContainer extends ViewGroup
{
    /**
     * Limit the maximum/minimum scrolling to prevent scrolling the container, 
     * so that no more children are visible. 
     * The value is relative to the size of the container (so 0.1 means 10% of the size of this container)
     */
    protected float mTranslationBounds = 0.1f;
    /**
     * The translation to be applyed to the container
     */
    protected PointF mTranslation;
    /**
     * The the current zoom factor. You might initialze it to a value smaller than 1, if you want to add some padding in the beginning.
     */
    protected float mScaleFactor = 1f;
    /**
     * The minimum scale factor to prevent endless zooming
     */
    protected float mScaleFactorMin = 0.8f;
    /**
     * The maximum scale factor to prevent endless zooming.
     */
    protected float mScaleFactorMax = 4f;
    /**
     * Used to indicate, whether or not this is the first touch event, which has no differences yet.
     */
    protected boolean mIsTouchStarted = false;
    /**
    * Distance of the fingers from the last touch event
    */
    protected float mStartDistance = 0;
    /**
     * Center of the two fingers from the last touch event.
     */
    protected PointF mStartTouchPoint = new PointF(0, 0);

    public ZoomContainer(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public ZoomContainer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public ZoomContainer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(createDrawMatrix());
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    /**
    * Cancel all child touch events, if there is more than one finger down.
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        boolean intercept = ev.getPointerCount() > 1;
        if (intercept)
        {
            mIsTouchStarted = false;
        }
        return intercept;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the transformation matrix for drawing and converting touch coordinates
     */
    protected Matrix createDrawMatrix()
    {
        // Make sure children are centered, if initial scroll factor is not 1.
        if (mTranslation == null)
        {
            mTranslation = new PointF(getWidth() * (1 - mScaleFactor) / 2f,
                    getHeight() * (1 - mScaleFactor) / 2f);
        }
        // Matrix used for drawing the view
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        matrix.postTranslate(mTranslation.x, mTranslation.y);
        return matrix;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the touch coordinates according to the current zoom and scroll,
     * for children to get the appropriate ones.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        // Matrix for Touch events
        Matrix mappingMatrix = new Matrix();
        // Touch event matrix needs to be inverted
        createDrawMatrix().invert(mappingMatrix);

        // Copy the touch Event that is being mapped
        MotionEvent transformEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        // Apply it's event mapping matrix
        transformEvent.transform(mappingMatrix);

        boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(transformEvent);
        transformEvent.recycle();
        return handled;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the new zoom and scroll respecting the difference to the last touch event.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mIsTouchStarted = false;
                return true;
        }
        // 
        if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1)
        {
            mIsTouchStarted = false;
            return true;
        }
        float[] currentPointArray = new float[]{event.getX(0),
                event.getY(0),
                event.getX(1),
                event.getY(1)};
        float currentDistance = mScaleFactor * getDistance(currentPointArray[0],
                currentPointArray[1],
                currentPointArray[2],
                currentPointArray[3]);
        Matrix transformation = createDrawMatrix();
        transformation.mapPoints(currentPointArray);
        PointF currentPoint = getPoint(currentPointArray[0],
                currentPointArray[1],
                currentPointArray[2],
                currentPointArray[3]);
        if (mIsTouchStarted)
        {
            float scaleFactorDifference = mScaleFactor;
            mScaleFactor = getBoundScaleFactor(mScaleFactor + (currentDistance / mStartDistance - 1));
            scaleFactorDifference -= mScaleFactor;
            PointF newTranslation = new PointF(mTranslation.x + currentPoint.x - mStartTouchPoint.x,
                    mTranslation.y + currentPoint.y - mStartTouchPoint.y);
            newTranslation.x += currentPoint.x * scaleFactorDifference;
            newTranslation.y += currentPoint.y * scaleFactorDifference;
            mTranslation = getBoundTranslation(newTranslation);
        }
        mStartTouchPoint = currentPoint;
        mStartDistance = currentDistance;
        mIsTouchStarted = true;
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    protected float getBoundValue(float value, float min, float max)
    {
        return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
    }

    protected PointF getBoundTranslation(PointF translation)
    {
        translation.x = getBoundValue(translation.x,
                -(getWidth() * (mScaleFactor - 1) + getWidth() * mTranslationBounds),
                getWidth() * mTranslationBounds);
        translation.y = getBoundValue(translation.y,
                -(getHeight() * (mScaleFactor - 1) + getHeight() * mTranslationBounds),
                getHeight() * mTranslationBounds);
        return translation;
    }

    protected float getBoundScaleFactor(float scaleFactor)
    {
        return getBoundValue(scaleFactor, mScaleFactorMin, mScaleFactorMax);
    }

    protected PointF getPoint(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        return new PointF(getCenter(x1, x2), getCenter(y1, y2));
    }

    protected float getCenter(float position1, float position2)
    {
        return (position1 + position2) / 2f;
    }

    protected float getDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        float distanceX = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
        float distanceY = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and create a new MotionEvent by providing coordinates.

Copy the existing event and then transform it using a matrix.

e.g. something like

```java
// Matrix used for drawing the view
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
matrix.postTranslate(panX, panY);
// used with canvas.concat(matrix);

// Matrix for Touch events
Matrix mappingMatrix = new Matrix();
// Touch event matrix needs to be inverted
matrix.invert(mappingMatrix);

// Copy the touch Event that is being mapped
MotionEvent transformEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
// Apply it's event mapping matrix
transformEvent.transform(mappingMatrix);
```

[Obtain copy documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#obtain(android.view.MotionEvent))

I do something very similar in my custom viewgroup for scaling MotionEvents to children in my [FixedHeaderTableLayout](https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout) Library.

The MotionEvent copying is done [here](https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout/blob/67100f914ab9555c210988d685cb00932f244e01/fixedheadertablelayout/src/main/java/com/github/zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout/FixedHeaderTableLayout.java#L563)

Comment: After some hard hours I made it working, thanks to your inputs. Check my answer for a full solution, if you are interessted in.